# Dynamic Comment Changing In Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have files one is /etc/passwd that contains three new user methun, salam and kalam and have another file in /methunfiles/mypractice/myfile/passwd which contains input as methun:xxx salam:firstboy kalam:secondboy in a tow columns. first column contains methun, salam, kalam and second column contains xxx, firstboy, secondboy. Now my job is to matches the /etc/passwd files first column with the first column of /methunfiles/mypractice/myfile/passwd 's first colimn. If any matches found then insert the /etc/passwd 's comment field 
with the second column of /methunfiles/mypractice/myfile/passwd file in same name found in first column of both. i have tried with the following code but no output found. I want to use loop here . Anybody help ? my output should like methun:x:501:502:xxx:......, salam:x:439:439:firstboy ...etc.

```
        mainUser=cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
        modifyUser=cat /methunfiles/mypractice/myfile/passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
        modifyComment=cat /methunfiles/mypractice/myfile/passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
        for muser in $mainUser
          do
             for moduser in $modifyUser
               do
                  for mcomment in $modifyComment
                   do
                    if ["$muser" == "$moduser" ]
                      chmod -c "$mcomment" $muser
                    fi
                done
            done
          done
```

Comment: Did you saw my code....i want to do this by for loop ..

Comment: I did see that. I chose not to use loops because I think you should see a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

the `join` command is what you need.

```
f1=/etc/passwd
f2=/methunfiles/mypractice/myfile/passwd

join -t: -j1 -o 2.1,2.2 <(sort -t: -k1,1 $f1) <(sort -t: -k1,1 $f2) |
while IFS=: read user new_comment; do
    if usermod -c "$new_comment" $user; then
        getent passwd $user
    else
        echo "could not modify comment field for $user"
    fi
done
```